# how to display images which are stored as string array in html?

Tags: java, javascript, html, json

I have been trying to load images which are in database(on local phone) .JSON talks to java and gets the byte array which i am encoding as 64 bit data and returns a string array . 
Now i am trying to parse the json data. I see the array but how do i read it or set it image tag in html . All answers are appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`data://` URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

For example, if the base64-encoded data is:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

then you'd drop that data into an image's `src` attribute like so:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

which draws this image:

[image: small red dot]

Comment: @David it's especially neat to be able to draw (anything) on a `<canvas>` and then render it as a regular `<img>` in the page using [`canvas.toDataURL()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl).